# Best way to code over 200 true/false items in Android?

Tags: java, android, input

I could use some help/guidance on this. I'm trying to develop a program that accepts input for over 200 true/false responses. Currently I only know how to do this by putting 200+ items in the XML and then do something like:

```
    etRaw[0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRaw0);
    etRaw[1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRaw1);
    etRaw[2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRaw2);
    etRaw[3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRaw3);
```

all the way down to the last item followed by a loop to read it all into an array. It seems this is a long hard way of doing something that might be infinitely easier.

I know this is somewhat vague, but if someone can advise me or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use RecyclerView, a LayoutManager, and an Adapter:

[image]

These components let you define one or more layouts, inflate (and/or recycle) views on demand, and initialize those views according to your data set as the user scrolls.

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to put your data into a collection object and populate a ListView.